# How does this work - How does the vbs script know it should open the file?

Tags: vbscript

I needed a vbs script that opens a `.xlsm` file, runs a macro in it and closes the file again.

Online I found a script that works perfectly.
Trouble is, I don't understand how.

This is the script :

```
Sub MacroExcel() 

  Dim ExcelApp 
  Dim ExcelFile


  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  Set ExcelFile = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\File1.xlsm") 
  
  ExcelApp.Visible = True   
  ExcelApp.Run "Macro1" 
  ExcelApp.Quit 

  Set ExcelFile = Nothing 
  Set ExcelApp = Nothing 

End Sub
```

How does this open the file in the first place? As I understand, this line  :

```
Set ExcelFile = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\File1.xlsm")
```

assigns a method to the variable `ExcelFile`. But then, `ExcelFile` is not used in the code anymore.

How does the script know that the file should actually be opened ?

Comment: The `Open()` method opens the file (i.e., it effectively opens a workbook) and returns a reference to it that is stored in `ExcelFile`. The use of the word File is somewhat misleading, a better name would have been ExcelWorkbook.

Answer (score 5):

> As I understand, this line :
>
> `Set ExcelFile = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\File1.xlsm")`
>
> assigns a
> method to the variable ExcelFile

That is where you understand it wrong. It doesn't assign a *method* to the variable `ExcelFile`, it assigns the **result** of **executing** the method `ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\File1.xlsm")`

You see, when you ask Excel to open a file, it not only opens the actual file in Excel, it also returns an object of type [Workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook)
It's this workbook object that is stored in the variable `ExcelFile`

Now you are entirely correct that in this snippet the actual workbook object is not used. So instead of assigning the result to a variable, they could have also executed the method and ignored the resulting object like this.

```
ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open "D:\File1.xlsm"
```